# How encrypt few columns of postgres database while using it with EF core in an ASP.NET core application?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, npgsql

I have an application based on NETCore 2.2.0. I am using Postgres as my database and using  EntityFramework.

Is there any way in which I can avoid directly using **pgcrypto** library, rather encrypt only a few columns of the table with the help of EF or npgsql or any other NuGet package?

Comment: I would take a look a [Model Extensibility Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730830/mef-plugins-and-ef-codefirst-how/8901068#8901068) to extend entity framework adding your .net crypto logic and thus avoid pgcrypto.

Answer (score 2):

You can manually encrypt and decrypt your columns before writing/reading them. One feature which can made very easy is EF Core's [value converters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/value-conversions) - simply set up one lambda to encrypt your value and another to decrypt it. The actual encryption/decryption is up to you.